# TemplateDoesNotExist at /website/, extended template

Tags: django, templates, django-templates, extends

Sorry if my question is not well written or anything, this is my first time posting here.
So, I'm trying Django and tries to use the generic templates of Django. I create a parent template named "layout.html".
It has three blocks, then I created a child extended from this "layout.html", check the files :

layout.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>{% block title %}Bleh bleh{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
```

etc...

index.html :

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %} My amazing index !!!{% endblock %}
```

etc...

These two files are in the same folder. But, here is my error :

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /rubriques/
```

(yes, rubriques is my namespace)

Here is a sample of the error :

```
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/rubriques/
Django Version:     1.5.1
Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    

layout.html

Exception Location:     /home/thomas/.virtualenvs/site/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in find_template, line 139
Python Executable:  /home/thomas/.virtualenvs/site/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.4


Error during template rendering

In template /home/thomas/projets/siteonglets/rubriques/templates/rubriques/index.html, error at line 1
```

I hope someone can help me, I don't really see where the error comes from !

Comment: Could you post your `views.py` please? Also your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting in `settings.py`. The problem might be corrected with doing in your index.html template `{% extends 'rubriques/layout.html' %}`

Comment: The problem was in TEMPLATE_DIRS. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the TEMPLATES_DIR in settings.py.

That way django will know where the templates are.

Comment: Heeeey, that was so easy ? Thanks a lot, I couldn't find without you. It's working !